# Find keywords in a call recording

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, keyword-search

I need to build a program which can find keywords in a list of call recordings. How can I do that? If there are any open source options please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what open source tools have you already looked at?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are describing is called Keyword Spotting or Spoken Term Detection. Open-source Speech Recognition toolkits [Kaldi](http://kaldi-asr.org/doc/kws.html) and [Sphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/faq/) have such feature. You'll need basic understanding of how speech recognition systems work, also find readily trained models for your language, which are provided by these toolkits, also at [Voxforge](http://voxforge.org/) website (for some languages). In the latter case you will need to convert model into your favorite toolkit's format. 
Note that these models won't provide production-level accuracy, so training of acoustic models on several thousands hours of audio data is needed in this case.